# Divide y into x parts

Tags: arithmetic

If I have 2 natural numbers **x** and **y**.

First, I want to know if I can break the number **y** into **x** distinct natural numbers.   Furthermore, if the answer is **yes**, then how to find the **x** distinct natural numbers.

Second, I want to know if I can break number **y** into any **m** distinct natural numbers.  Furthermore, if the answer is **yes**, then how to find the **m** distinct natural numbers.

Is there a particular algorithm or a way to think about this? I often come around this problem and it always troubles me. I am open to as many ways to think about this problem as there could be.Looking at other people's logic would help me build logic myself.

Comment: This is not clear.  What's the difference between the two questions? It looks like you just changed the variable names.  In any case, if $1+2+3+\cdots +x≤y$ then you can do it, otherwise you can't.

Comment: @lulu in the first case, we can break the number y only into x parts, whereas in the second case, you can break the number y into any number of parts.

Comment: Obviously you can break $y$ into $m$ distinct parts for *some* $m$, just take $m=1$.

Comment: @lulu I think you're wrong. if y = 11, and x = 4, then your condition is satisfied but we still cannot break 11 into 4 distinct parts

Comment: $11=1+2+3+5$.  $\quad$

Comment: @lulu oh, alright, and is there some particular algorithm or way to find these numbers? because y could be a large number?

Comment: I gave you an algorithm.  Just write $1+2+\cdots +(x-1)$ then add whatever you need to get to $y$.  By assumption that last term is at least $x$, hence distinct from all your other terms.  Obviously the answer is not generally unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to write a natural number $N$ as a sum of $k$ distinct natural numbers? Natural numbers here are understood to be strictly positive.

First, let's answer a related question: What is the smallest number that can be written as a sum of $k$ distinct natural numbers? This would be $N_0 = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + k$. For example, the smallest sum for $k = 4$ is $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$. Any number smaller than $10$ cannot be written as a sum of $4$ distinct natural numbers. The smallest number is thus the [$k$-th triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). The formula for calculating the $k$-th triangular number $T_k = k(k+1)/2$. If you want to know whether a natural number $N$ can be written as the sum of $k$ distinct natural numbers, calculate the $k$-th triangular number. The answer is yes if and only if $N \ge T_k$.

If the answer to the above question is yes and you want to find out one such sum, then the following sum works: $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (k-1) + (N - T_{k-1})$. For example, take $N = 17$ and $k = 5$. This can be written as a sum of distinct natural numbers since $T_k = 5(5+1)/2 = 15 < 17$. The sum is
$$\begin{align}
&\,\,1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + (17 - T_4) \\
=&\,\,1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + (17 - 10) \\
=&\,\,1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 7
\end{align}$$
This sum is not unique. Another is $1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 6$.

Your second question is less clear. If any number of natural numbers is fine, then every number greater than$\,2$ can be written as a sum of two distinct natural numbers, namely $1$ and $N-1$. Every natural number can also be trivially written as a sum of one distinct natural number: $N$.